# Does there exist a polynomial $f(x)$ with real coefficients such that $f(x)^2$ has fewer nonzero coefficients than $f(x)$?

Tags: polynomials, problem-solving

I saw this problem on a problem set and I have absolutely no idea how to proceed in a feasible way.

> Does there exist a polynomial $f(x)$ with real coefficients such that $f(x)^2$ has fewer nonzero coefficients than $f(x)$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For examples, [please see this.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SparsePolynomialSquare.html) Not simple!

Comment: @AndréNicolas , Thank you but is there an elegant way to find those polynomials? I

Comment: You are welcome.  Quick I do not know.

Comment: The reason for my quest is that this problem is taken from a problem set which is aimed at undergraduates.

Comment: Degree 12 is smallest, per reference given by André Nicolas.  Might be tough for undergraduates.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** What happens if you consider a truncated Taylor series for $\sqrt{1-x}$ ? For instance:

$$\left(1-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{x^3}{16}-\frac{5 x^4}{128}\right)^2 = 1-x+\frac{7 x^5}{128}+\frac{7 x^6}{512}+\frac{5 x^7}{1024}+\frac{25 x^8}{16384}$$
with about the same number of non-zero coefficients. Are you able to adjust a couple of coefficients in the LHS in order to prove your claim? For instance:
$$\left(1-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{x^3}{16}+ \frac{x^4}{64}\right)^2=1-x+\frac{7 x^4}{64}-\frac{x^7}{512}+\frac{x^8}{4096}.$$
However, in order to find a polynomial whose square has fewer non-zero terms than the original polynomial, [you have](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SparsePolynomialSquare.html) to consider polynomials with degree at least $12$.

Comment: Interesting! Can you cite a proof that no polynomial exists with degree less than $12$ and having the desired property?

Comment: @TomLynd: to be honest, I never read the proof, but Wikipedia gives it is due to Abbott (2002) and it is more or less an extensive computation through Groebner basis.