# About sparse polynomial squares

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, convolution

Given $p\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$, we define the weigth of $p$ as:
$$ W(p) = \#\{n\in\mathbb{N}: [x^n]\,p(x)\neq 0\} $$
i.e. as the number of non-zero terms.

By [playing a bit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368825/does-there-exist-a-polynomial-fx-with-real-coefficients-such-that-fx2-h/1368836#1368836) with the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1-x}$ in $x=0$ it is not difficult to prove that for an infinite number of rational polynomials $W(p^2)=W(p)$ holds. Moreover, it is [well-known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SparsePolynomialSquare.html) that for an infinite number of rational polynomials, with degree at least $12$,

$$ W(p^2) = W(p)-1 $$
holds. Now I wonder:

> - Is there some $p\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $W(p^2)=W(p)-2$?
> - Is $W(p)-W(p^2)$ bounded by some constant?
> - If not, is it possible to solve $W(p)-W(p^2)\geq k$ through some tensor trick?
> - What is the minimum degree of a polynomial for which $W(p)-W(p^2)=k$?
>    Crude bounds are also welcome.